# How can I move the entire data segment 2 bytes to the right efficiently?

Tags: assembly, optimization, nasm, x86-16

I want to move the entire data segment 2 bytes to the right while optimizing for size in nasm,

My best Idea is:

```
    std
    pusha
    push es
    push ds
    pop es
    mov si, bp
    lea cx, [bp+0x1]
    lea di, [bp+0x2]
    rep movsb
    pop es
    popa
```

But it takes 17 bytes...

Comment: So your "data segment" is bp+1 bytes long?  In other words, bp points to the last byte, rather than one past the last byte as would be more normal?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes

Comment: @NateEldredge The only memory access done here is the `movsb`. The segment of an effective address doesn't matter to `lea`.

Comment: This is 16-bit real mode code. Offset inside segment is 0 -FFFF.  So if you want to move 2 bytes to the right it means 2 bytes will be in new segment and FFFD bytes will be in old segment.

Comment: @ecm: Oh right, how silly of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 11 bytes

It seems the overhead of setting up for `rep movsb` is not worth it, so let's do a simple loop instead.

```
     4 00000000 89EB                            mov bx, bp
     5 00000002 43                              inc bx
     6                                  again:
     7 00000003 4B                              dec bx
     8 00000004 8A07                            mov al, [bx]
     9 00000006 884702                          mov [bx+2], al
    10 00000009 75F8                            jnz again
```

The awkward `inc bx` at the beginning is to avoid an off-by-one error, since we have to copy `bp+1` bytes.

If not for the quirk that `dec` doesn't set the carry flag, we could have shaved off one byte with:

```
     4 00000000 89EB                            mov bx, bp
     5                                  again:
     6 00000002 8A07                            mov al, [bx]
     7 00000004 884702                          mov [bx+2], al
     8 00000007 4B                              dec bx
     9 00000008 72F8                            jnc again ; BUG
```

so that we effectively compare `bx` with -1 instead of with 0.  However, if `bp` is guaranteed to be less than 32K, then you could use `jns again` and be down to 10 bytes.

I also tried some versions using `lodsb / mov [si+3], al` with `df=1` to do the load and decrement together, but the problem is that since `lodsb` doesn't set flags, we need something like `cmp si, -1` to check for loop termination, and that's three more bytes.  So I couldn't get that version shorter than 11.

Comment: It doesn't save anything in this case, but you could skip the initial iteration's `dec bx` using [a skipping instruction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/235553#235553).

Comment: No, wait, that messes up the Zero Flag in this case.